# React native, Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image` I'm getting that error while uploading image.
I used image picker to pick image and made it component but it's not picking up source below is my code of image picker
FormImage.js

```
class FormImage extends Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  }

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
      this.props.formikProps.setFieldValue("image", result.uri);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._pickImage}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {!this.props.image && (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={colors.medium}
              name="camera"
              size={40}
            />
          )}
          {this.props.image && (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: this.props.image }} />
          )}
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know why it's showing that error i will share my formik code below
AddPost.js

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  title: Yup.string().required().min(5).max(15).label("Title"),
  des: Yup.string().required().min(15).max(200).label("Description"),
  image: Yup.mixed(),
});

class AddPost extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ title: "", des: "", image: null }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          this.props.addPost(values);
          console.log(values);
        }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        {(value) => (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior="position"
            keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 100}
          >
            <FormImage formikProps={value} image={value.values.image} />
            <Text style={styles.error}>
              {value.touched.image && value.errors.image}
            </Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Title"
              onChangeText={value.handleChange("title")}
              style={styles.input}
              value={value.values.title}
              onBlur={value.handleBlur("title")}
            />
```

below is my home screen code
home.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  addPost = (posts) => {
    posts.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        post: [...prevState.post, posts],
        modal: false,
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modal} animationType="slide">
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
              <AddPost addPost={this.addPost} />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <Card
                title={item.title}
                subTitle={item.des}
                image={item.image}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", item)}
              />
            </>
```

can someone tell me whats going on why it's not picking the source :/

Comment: It most likely has to do with the value of `this.props.image`, so try logging that out. The value of uri should be "a string representing the resource identifier for the image". So make sure that is actually the case and you're not passing something else. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.

Comment: it's an Imager pickers i can't pass string i used the way mention in expo image picker doc

Comment: maybe you have image as null, in initial values in formik.

Comment: i need to add image: null in state?