# React Native, Updating user profile image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update user profile pic by using Image picker but when I select an Image to update it, it's not updating and just and default image also get removed. I'm really getting a lot of problems by using Image picker with class base, please someone help

Here is my code

```
class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    userImage: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
    userName: "John Cena",
    userInfo: "The champ is here",
    modal: false,
    image: null,
    hasCameraPermission: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  }

  pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={this.pickImage}
            style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
          >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="camera"
              size={30}
              color={colors.white}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {!this.state.image && (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={this.state.userImage} />
          )}
          {this.state.image && (
            <Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{ uri: this.setState.userImage }}
            />
          )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo, `source={this.state.userImage}` rather than source={this.setState...}
And the state you are setting up, is `image`, so it should be `this.state.image`

Comment: thnx it worked, I need to do more work with classes, can you help in in another problem? related to image picker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64173599/react-native-failed-prop-type-invalid-prop-source-supplied-to-image?noredirect=1#comment113485346_64173599

Comment: that one please

Comment: if this answered your question, please mark or upvote it, thanks.